# Phone not booting after OEM lock

Tags: fastboot

Device: Yu Yunique

I flashed stock fastboot ROM (YU OS) and it booted. After that, I did `fastboot oem lock` and the phone not booting. Fastboot doesn't allowing me to flash another ROM too.

I googled about this and it says I need to enabled USB debugging from developer tools. But since the phone is not booting, I am not able to do this.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2):

The phone has less chances of turning on. Especially if the software that resides on the phone has a different and or modified boot or recovery image as compared to the stock images.

Easy and wise option is to reload its Operating System because luckily you have a computer. No matter how MTP or other transfer protocols may fail to work, VCOM which is responsible for preloading the firmware on MTK devices will never fail. This is the final solution for any strangely bricked device.

So. Assuming Your Yu Yunique is Yu 4711. Snatch its stock firmware from [here](https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B12zEp6BhQ4xZVNPZUJZaVAtcGc&export=download) and latest SP Flash Tool from [here](https://spflashtool.com/download/SP_Flash_Tool_v5.1924_Win.zip) and VCOM drivers from [this mega link](https://mega.nz/#!B9YwGQ5Z!M9tDl7Z0Z1IwmryWwdrJPwuxNkPJ0QMozfDXHKtbtok)

Read on how to install VCOM drivers [here](https://www.getdroidtips.com/install-mediatek-mt65xx-usb-vcom-drivers/) and install them to your PC

Extract both the Flash Tool and the firmware with any suitable program like WinRAR.

Run the Flash Tool exe file with a greenish icon and it will open up a window.

Click on scatter loading option. It will open up a pop up window. Guide it to the path where the extracted firmware is and load the scatter file which is a txt document. Can be written something like "MT65XX_Scatter.txt"

It will show you associations of different partitions to respective files e.g. preloaded, boot, recovery, system etc. uncheck everything and check only, boot, recovery, system, userdata and cache

Turn off your phone. While disconnected from your PC. press download on the Flash Tool and connect your phone.

Wait for it to complete flashing and unplug and enjoy. If it doesn't start flashing repeat the step above with volume down button pressed and held down while connecting the cable.

It must work if everything is done correctly. If the device mentioned isn't your exact phone model. You can tell me your model and I'll give you a link to its stock ROM which you will then use to revive it.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake was to leave "USB debugging" and "Allow OEM unlock" options unchecked. Just make sure both are ticked when phone is on or you have to visit service center. Sadly, no other solution is there.

Answer (score 1):

Reconnect your phone to PC using the USB cable. Then, try re-entering the fastboot mode by pressing the corresponding key combination (may be power button + low volume). Hold it for a few seconds. Once the phone enters fastboot mode, send the command `fastboot oem unlock` from your PC.